# Installing Software packages on Ubuntu Studio

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I am wondering how to install software packages from a web browser on Ubuntu Studio. Specifically, I want to know which distribution to select as I am installing Slack.  Do I use the plain "Ubuntu" or do I use "Kubuntu?"  [Here is a screenshot of options I am presented with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeYim.png)

Comment: In most cases it doesn't matter. But in this specific case it is hard to tell what diffference there is between packages. I would choose Ubuntu, because the Studio doesn't use KDE.

Answer (score 2):

The detailed instructions for installation of slack are the same for [Ubuntu](https://snapcraft.io/install/slack/ubuntu) and [Kubuntu](https://snapcraft.io/install/slack/kubuntu). In both cases you just need to run

```
sudo snap install slack --classic
```

There is no need to install `snapd` since all currently supported versions of Ubuntustudio have `snapd` installed and enabled by default.